# Norm of an integral operator on the space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

The following is a question I came up with when I was studying the same problem in dimension 1 (for which also  I have the questions that follows) but I put in generality.

> Let $U_1, U_2 \subset \mathbb R^n$ bounded,  $\displaystyle f:U_2 \to
>  \mathbb R$, and $\displaystyle K: \overline U_1 \times \overline U_2
>  \to \mathbb R$ continuous. For $\displaystyle x \in U_1 $ define the
>   integral operator $\displaystyle T_K : C(U_2) \to C(U_1) $ defined by
>     $$ (T_K f)(x):= \int_{U_2} K(x,y) f(y) \text{d} y $$

I think that it is $ \displaystyle \|T_K \| = \sup_{x \in U_1} \int_{U_2} |K(x,y)| \text{d} y $, but I am don't know how to prove it. I have shown that this $\sup$ is the upper bound for the norm of the operator, but I can't find an $f$ that achieves it.

*Also I have one more question:*

> If instead of $f$ being contninuous we suppose that $f$ is only
>   Lebesgue measurable, what is changing, or everything is the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Which norm are you looking for? You need to specify a space before you can ask for a norm.

Comment: @RayYang: I am looking the norm of the operator $T_K$. Although I think it is clear, and I don't understand why has been downvoted, I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the norm of $T_K$ is indeed

$$\lVert T_K\rVert = \sup_{x\in U_1} \int_{U_2} \lvert K(x,y)\rvert\,dy.$$

However, in general, there is no $f \neq 0$ with $\lVert T_K(f)\rVert = \lVert T_K\rVert\cdot \lVert f\rVert$, so you need to see that you can come arbitrarily close. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, pick an $x\in U_1$ with

$$\int_{U_2} \lvert K(x,y)\rvert\,dy > \lVert T_K\rVert - \varepsilon/2.$$

Then consider the function $h(y) = \overline{\sigma(K(x,y))}$ on $U_2$, where

$$\sigma(z) = \begin{cases} 0 &, z = 0\\ \frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert} &, z \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

is the sign function. We have $\lvert h(y)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $y\in U_2$ and

$$\int_{U_2} K(x,y)h(y)\,dy = \int_{U_2} \lvert K(x,y)\rvert\,dy.$$

If $h$ happens to be continuous, we already have found a function in $C(U_2)$ with $\lVert T_K(f)\rVert \geqslant (\lVert T_K\rVert-\varepsilon)\lVert f\rVert$. But generally, $h$ will not be continuous, and thus we need to approximate it by continuous functions. Extend $h$ to a function on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the value $0$ outside $U_2$. Then choose a mollifier function $\eta$ with $0 \leqslant \eta(t)$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\eta(t)\,dt = 1$, and $\eta$ continuous. For $\delta > 0$ define

$$h_\delta(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta(t)h(y- \delta t)\,dt.$$

The functions $h_\delta$ are continuous, satisfy $\lvert h_\delta(y)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $y$, and $\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} \lVert h_\delta - h\rVert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} = 0$.

From the latter, it follows that

$$\int_{U_2} K(x,y) h_\delta(y)\,dy \xrightarrow{\delta \to 0} \int_{U_2} K(x,y) h(y)\,dy$$

since $K$ is bounded. Thus, for small enough $\delta > 0$, we have

$$\left\lvert \int_{U_2} K(x,y)h_\delta(y) - \lvert K(x,y)\rvert\,dy \right\rvert < \varepsilon/2,$$

and thus

$$\lVert T_K(h_\delta)\rVert > (\lVert T_K\rVert - \varepsilon)\lVert h_\delta\rVert.$$

> If instead of $f$ being contninuous we suppose that $f$ is only Lebesgue measurable, what is changing, or everything is the same.

We need to demand that $f$ is integrable, not only measurable. The result remains the same, but in that case, we can directly work with $h$ and don't need to approximate it by continuous functions.

If we drop the requirement that $K$ is continuous, and consider $K \in L^\infty (U_1\times U_2)$ instead, so $T_K \colon L^1(U_2) \to L^\infty(U_1)$, we must replace the supremum by an essential supremum.

Comment: Thank's! I have two questions: (1) $h$ will be continuous depending on particular kernels $K$ right? (2) If $f$ is integrable why don't we use approximation by continuous functions ? And also if we assume that $f$ is continuous then it is integrable. So the first step with $h$ is for which functions?

Comment: If $K(x,\,\cdot\,)$ has no zeros, $h$ will be continuous, but if $K(x,\,\cdot\,)$ has zeros, it won't. For real-valued $K$, if $K(x,\,\cdot\,)$ doesn't change sign in any zero, one could choose a continuous $h$ ($h \equiv \pm 1$), but generally, one needs to handle sign changes gracefully. If we extend the domain of $T_K$ to integrable functions, then the constructed $h$ already belongs to the domain, so we don't need to approximate it with functions in the domain of $T_K$. We use $h$ to get a function with $\lVert f\rVert_\infty\leqslant 1$ such that ...

Comment: ... $\int_{U_2}K(x,y)f(y)\,dy = \int_{U_2} \lvert K(x,y)\rvert\,dy$, in order to get a function that almost achieves the norm of $T_K$. Now, when the constructed $h$ is not in the domain of $T_K$, we need to approximate it. If it is in the domain, we can directly use it.

Comment: Dear Daniel Fisher, everything is clear now! Thank you very much for time!